# how to test if maven/m2e plugin is configured correctly in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I am trying to build a project in eclipse and then start working on it. i have pulled it from my companies git hub repo and then imported into eclipse via maven.

when i do mvn clean install in the command line, it all succeeds and all the tests pass. in eclipse however, when i run the junit tests, some fail and i get errors. my boss says he thinks that eclipse is not configured correctly. how can i ensure that the eclipse is pointing at maven correctly? and that everything is inline and working as it should? i am working on eclipse kepler and really need to solve this soon.

Comment: Maybe the M2_HOME or M2 environment variable isn't the same in m2e?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to confirm the installation you can check that in Eclipse as below.

In Eclipse Go to Windows --> Preferences --> Maven --> Installations

There you can find if Eclipse uses internal Maven from your suite or any external Maven is being pointed. You can as well Add or Delete any new Maven versions if you want to.